# Different values of state in different places

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm currently learning react and came to the following problem.

When I start dragging div I update state writing div's id in it.
useEffect - writes that it's updated.
console.log() before return does the same.
So if I'm not mistaken, it comfirms that state updated. (I used it to debug and to see if state even updates)

But when dropHandler runs, it says that startBlock is ''. So it doesn't contain value.

```
export function SomePage() {
    const [startBlock, setStartBlock] = useState('') # using this state to store id of start div.
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log("changed to", startBlock)
    }, [startBlock])


    function dragStartHandler(e) {
      setStartBlock(e.currentTarget.parentElement.id);
    }

    function dropHandler(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log('drop', startBlock)
    
    }
    console.log(startBlock)
    return (
      <div draggable dragStartHandler={dragStartHandler} dropHandler={dropHandler}> # simplified doesn't really matter
    )
    
}
```

I know that useState is async. But as I already said, useEffect printed that value was updated. So I'm quite confused.
The questions are:

1. Why startBlock in dropHandler doesn't have value?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: vanilla html doesn't have `draggable` attribute, please make a reproduced version.

Comment: @Enfieldli yes it does https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/draggable

Answer (score 0):

The attributes you're looking for are called `onDragStart` and `onDragEnd`. Correct the names and it works properly.

```
export function SomePage() {
    const [startBlock, setStartBlock] = useState('') # using this state to store id of start div.
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
       console.log("changed to", startBlock)
    }, [startBlock])


    function dragStartHandler(e) {
      setStartBlock(e.currentTarget.parentElement.id);
    }

    function dropHandler(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log('drop', startBlock)
    
    }
    console.log(startBlock)
    return (
      <div draggable onDragStart={dragStartHandler} onDragEnd={dropHandler}> # simplified doesn't really matter
    )
    
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-od6bcr?file=/index.js

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is not the case, my bad I didn't provide all info. I have two divs. When I start dragging one of them, startBlock updates state using dragStart, then I drop first div over the second, which calls dropHandler. The thing is that dragStart sets state, but when I drop div state is empty